# grey square icon as android notification icon when android app in forground(active)

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

in my react native android app, for implementing of cloud messaging, i use this tutorial for android devices:

https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591

and i set my notification icon with put this to androidmanifest.xml

```
  <meta-data    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                      android:resource="@drawable/notif_icon"
        />
```

that i set my notif icon that be in drawable folder in src/main/res.

i correctly give my notify from firebase console and try it from my laravel backend.

when the app is in background, my icon was shown very well(notif_icon is a white image with transparent back).but when i am in the app, and notification come(from console or backend) the little icon doesnt set.but big icon exist that is ic_luncher icon in mipmap.
how can i handle this that i set little icon in notification when app is active(forgrounds)